# how to optimize sql query with many conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

table station_tbl:

```
station_name   |  fare_adult |  fare_child |  fare_OKU |  type |    stationid

New City            2.00         1.00         1.00       0            19900
Old Village         2.00         1.00         1.00       0            54900
Old City            5.00         2.50         2.50       1            23100
New Castle          1.00         0.50         0.50       1            22900
Adult                                                    2              0
Child                                                    2              1
OKU                                                      2              2
Single                                                   3              0
Return                                                   3              1
```

my query: display ticket info

```
SELECT
    A.ticketid,
    B.station_name AS stationid,
    c.station_name AS destination,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108) AS TIME,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 103) AS Date,
    D.station_name AS ticket_type,
    e.station_name AS journey_type,
    amount,
    issuedby
FROM ticketcollections AS A, 
    station_tbl AS B, 
    station_tbl AS c, 
    station_tbl AS D, 
    station_tbl AS e
WHERE A.ticketidparent = '" + Request("ParentId") + "'
    AND A.stationid = B.stationid
    AND B.type = 0
    AND A.destination = c.stationid
    AND c.type = 0
    AND A.ticket_type = D.stationid
    AND D.type = 4
    AND A.journey_type = e.stationid
    AND e.type = 3
```

I have combined all the data in 1 table.

This table just for storing name for station name and also ticket type.

because in table `ticketcollections` just store `code (1, 2, 3, 4)`. So when I want to print ticket then I will refer to this `station_tbl` for display naming purpose.

Please help me if this query will make the query too slow.

On my PC it is fast but on user's PC it is slow.

I have refered 2 tables only.

Comment: Please provide **ticketcollections** details with Insert.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    A.ticketid,
    B.station_name AS stationid,
    B.station_name AS destination,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108) AS TIME,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 103) AS Date,
    B.station_name AS ticket_type,
    B.station_name AS journey_type,
    amount,
    issuedby
FROM ticketcollections A
    station_tbl AS B,
WHERE A.ticketidparent = '" + Request("ParentId") + "'
    AND A.stationid = B.stationid
    AND B.type in(0,4,3)
```

Comment: I Don't think OP will be proper

Comment: OP has room for many things to improve in his table design/query.

Comment: this query seems ok comapred to mine.let me try this first.tq

Answer (score 0):

do you have any indices on the tables?  I would suggest putting them at least on stationId for ticketcollections and station_tbl and on station_tbl type.

Comment: yes i have index.column 'id' and it is autoincrement. just now i add another index-column 'type'. but i'm not sure the efficiency of the process.